# Splitting a toString from a SuperClass

Tags: split, tostring, stringbuilder

I have a class toString:

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder animalString = new StringBuilder(); 
        return animalString.append("Animal [breed=").append(breed).append(", weight in Kilos=").append(weight).append("]").toString();
    }
```

And then I have a subclass calling the above toString which I then try to split so I can add information into it for the subclasses own toString:

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        String animal = (super.toString());
        String[] tempString = animal.split("Animal [");
        String animalString = tempString[1];
        StringBuilder animalSB = new StringBuilder();
        return animalSB.append("Cat [hunts=").append(hunts).append(animalString).toString();
    }
```

However at this point it pitches a fit. I'm probably doing something wrong, but for the life of me I'm not sure what it is. I'm probably over complicating it but any suggestions would be most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `split()` method takes a string that is used as a regular expression.  If you read about regular expressions (I strongly recommend you do), the character '[' has a special meaning other than the literal meaning you intended.  Therefore, you must escape it by preceding it with '\\'.

change that line to `String[] tempString = animal.split("Animal \\[");` and it should work.

Comment: Brilliant! I was on the right track, but it was my lack of knowledge for the "[" character. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. There are other characters with special meanings, like curly brackets, period, etc.  When you get a chance, check out those sites I recommended, and play with it.